# Trouble with Apache Ant Tutorial - JUnit

Tags: ant, junit

I'm trying to following apache's ANT tutorial:

http://ant.apache.org/manual/index.html

I'm currently at the JUnit portion, but I keep getting errors related to not being able to find the junit.framework package.

I believe I've followed the tutorial exactly as follows - Here are the details:

-----My file structure-----

```
build.xml
/build
../classes
/lib
..log4j-1.2.8.jar
myManifest
/src
..HelloWorldTest.java
..log4j.properties
../oata
....HelloWorld.java
```

-----Sources-----

myManifest:

```
Main-Class: oata.HelloWorld
```

build.xml:

```
<project name ="HelloWorld" basedir="." default="main">
    <property name="src.dir" value="src" />
    <property name="build.dir" value="build" />
    <property name="classes.dir" value="${build.dir}/classes" />
    <property name="jar.dir"    value="${build.dir}/jar" />
    <property name="lib.dir"    value="lib" />

    <path id="classpath">
        <fileset dir="${lib.dir}" includes="**/*.jar" />
    </path>

    <property name="main-class" value="oata.HelloWorld" />

    <target name="clean">
        <delete dir="${build.dir}"/>
    </target>

    <target name="compile">
        <mkdir dir="${classes.dir}"/>
        <javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${classes.dir}" classpathref="classpath" />
        <copy todir="${classes.dir}" >
            <fileset dir="${src.dir}" excludes="**/*.java" />
        </copy>
    </target>

    <target name="jar" depends="compile">
        <mkdir dir="${jar.dir}" />
        <jar destfile="${jar.dir}/${ant.project.name}.jar" basedir="${classes.dir}">
            <manifest>
                <attribute name="Main-Class" value="${main-class}" />
            </manifest>
        </jar>
    </target>

    <target name="run" depends="jar">
        <java fork="true" classname="${main-class}">
            <classpath>
                <path refid="classpath"/>
            <path id="application" location="${jar.dir}/${ant.project.name}.jar"/>
            </classpath>
        </java>
    </target>

    <target name="junit" depends="jar">
            <junit printsummary="yes">
                <classpath>
                    <path refid="classpath"/>
                    <path refid="application"/>
                </classpath>

                <batchtest fork="yes">
                    <fileset dir="${src.dir}" includes="*Test.java"/>
                </batchtest>
            </junit>
        </target>

    <target name="clean-build" depends="clean,jar" />

    <target name="main" depends="clean,run" />
</project>
```

HelloWorldTest.java:

```
public class HelloWorldTest extends junit.framework.TestCase {

    public void testNothing() {
    }

    public void testWillAlwaysFail() {
        fail("An error message");
    }

}
```

HelloWorld.java

```
package oata;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class HelloWorld {
    static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(HelloWorld.class);

    public static void main(String [] args){
        logger.info("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

log4j.properties:

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, stdout

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%m%n
```

---Output---

```
 ant -verbose junit
Apache Ant(TM) version 1.8.2 compiled on June 20 2012
Trying the default build file: build.xml
Buildfile: /Users/jtyler/Projects/AntHelloWorld/build.xml
Detected Java version: 1.6 in: /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
Detected OS: Mac OS X
parsing buildfile /Users/jtyler/Projects/AntHelloWorld/build.xml with URI = file:/Users/jtyler/Projects/AntHelloWorld/build.xml
Project base dir set to: /Users/jtyler/Projects/AntHelloWorld
parsing buildfile jar:file:/usr/share/ant/lib/ant.jar!/org/apache/tools/ant/antlib.xml with URI = jar:file:/usr/share/ant/lib/ant.jar!/org/apache/tools/ant/antlib.xml from a zip file
Build sequence for target(s) `junit' is [compile, jar, junit]
Complete build sequence is [compile, jar, junit, clean, run, main, clean-build, ]

compile:
    [mkdir] Skipping /Users/jtyler/Projects/AntHelloWorld/build/classes because it already exists.
    [javac] /Users/jtyler/Projects/AntHelloWorld/build.xml:20: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds
    [javac] HelloWorldTest.java added as HelloWorldTest.class doesn't exist.
    [javac] /Users/jtyler/Projects/AntHelloWorld/src/log4j.properties skipped - don't know how to handle it
    [javac] oata/HelloWorld.java added as oata/HelloWorld.class doesn't exist.
    [javac] Compiling 2 source files to /Users/jtyler/Projects/AntHelloWorld/build/classes
    [javac] Using modern compiler
    [javac] Compilation arguments:
    [javac] '-d'
    [javac] '/Users/jtyler/Projects/AntHelloWorld/build/classes'
    [javac] '-classpath'
    [javac] '/Users/jtyler/Projects/AntHelloWorld/build/classes:/Users/jtyler/Projects/AntHelloWorld/lib/log4j-1.2.8.jar:/usr/share/ant/lib/ant-launcher.jar:/usr/share/ant/lib/ant-antlr.jar:/usr/share/ant/lib/ant-jmf.jar:/usr/share/ant/lib/ant-junit.jar:/usr/share/ant/lib/ant-junit4.jar:/usr/share/ant/lib/ant-swing.jar:/usr/share/ant/lib/ant-testutil.jar:/usr/share/ant/lib/ant.jar'
    [javac] '-sourcepath'
    [javac] '/Users/jtyler/Projects/AntHelloWorld/src'
    [javac] '-g:none'
    [javac] 
    [javac] The ' characters around the executable and arguments are
    [javac] not part of the command.
    [javac] Files to be compiled:
    [javac]     /Users/jtyler/Projects/AntHelloWorld/src/HelloWorldTest.java
    [javac]     /Users/jtyler/Projects/AntHelloWorld/src/oata/HelloWorld.java
    [javac] /Users/jtyler/Projects/AntHelloWorld/src/HelloWorldTest.java:1: package junit.framework does not exist
    [javac] public class HelloWorldTest extends junit.framework.TestCase {
    [javac]                                                    ^
    [javac] /Users/jtyler/Projects/AntHelloWorld/src/HelloWorldTest.java:7: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : method fail(java.lang.String)
    [javac] location: class HelloWorldTest
    [javac]         fail("An error message");
    [javac]         ^
    [javac] 2 errors

BUILD FAILED
/Users/jtyler/Projects/AntHelloWorld/build.xml:20: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Javac.compile(Javac.java:1150)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Javac.execute(Javac.java:912)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:390)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:411)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:809)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:217)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)

Total time: 0 seconds
```

Is there something I'm missing that's needed to be included that was (or wasn't) mentioned in the tutorial?

**EDIT**: Based on Alex's inquiries, I tested to see if I had ant's junit jars in my shared directories (which I do):

```
$ ls /usr/share/ant/lib/ant-junit*.jar
/usr/share/ant/lib/ant-junit.jar    /usr/share/ant/lib/ant-junit4.jar
```

I also tried to manually put ant-junit, ant-junit4.jar, and junit.jar into my project's lib directory, with the following results (all errors) after running **ant clean junit**:

- junit.jar - /Users/jtyler/Projects/AntHelloWorld/build.xml:45: Reference application not found.
- ant-junit.jar: package junit.framework does not exist
- ant-junit.jar and ant.junit4.jar: package junit.framework does not exist
- ant-junit4.jar: package junit.framework does not exist

**EDIT** The whole error when only junit.jar is included in the lib folder and calling **ant clean junit** is:

```
$ ant clean junit
Buildfile: /Users/jtyler/Projects/AntHelloWorld/build.xml

clean:
   [delete] Deleting directory /Users/jtyler/Projects/AntHelloWorld/build

compile:
    [mkdir] Created dir: /Users/jtyler/Projects/AntHelloWorld/build/classes
    [javac] /Users/jtyler/Projects/AntHelloWorld/build.xml:20: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds
    [javac] Compiling 2 source files to /Users/jtyler/Projects/AntHelloWorld/build/classes
     [copy] Copying 1 file to /Users/jtyler/Projects/AntHelloWorld/build/classes

jar:
    [mkdir] Created dir: /Users/jtyler/Projects/AntHelloWorld/build/jar
      [jar] Building jar: /Users/jtyler/Projects/AntHelloWorld/build/jar/HelloWorld.jar

junit:

BUILD FAILED
/Users/jtyler/Projects/AntHelloWorld/build.xml:45: Reference application not found.
```

Comment: do you have a junit jar in your lib directory?

Comment: It **does** work when I add junit to the lib directory (/lib/junit.jar) However I'm a bit thrown off since it wasn't mentioned to do that in the tutorial, and because of this line in it: "...In this step we will introduce the usage of the JUnit [3] testframework in combination with Ant. Because Ant has a built-in JUnit 3.8.2 you could start directly using it."

Comment: you're right that it doesn't need to be included explicitly in your lib directory, looking at the classpath which is used, can you check if following files exist: `/usr/share/ant/lib/ant-junit.jar` and `/usr/share/ant/lib/ant-junit4.jar`

Comment: `ls /usr/share/ant/lib/ant-*.jar
/usr/share/ant/lib/ant-antlr.jar /usr/share/ant/lib/ant-launcher.jar
/usr/share/ant/lib/ant-jmf.jar  /usr/share/ant/lib/ant-swing.jar
/usr/share/ant/lib/ant-junit.jar /usr/share/ant/lib/ant-testutil.jar
/usr/share/ant/lib/ant-junit4.jar` - so they do exist. **Sorry - I need to revise my answer to the previous comment**: It doesn't compile when junit.jar is in there (I tested ant jar by accident), but it does give the following error now with junit.jar:
/Users/jtyler/Projects/AntHelloWorld/build.xml:45: Reference application not found.

Comment: Jtyler, better update the information directly in the question, so that people have easier task understanding the issue. Use `edit` link for that. You may also mark new contents with **Edit** or something.

Comment: Ok, so with junit.jar you have gone farther, up to line 45. What is the whole message error then. It seems the right way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On top of including the junit.jar file within my lib dir, I added the following line to my build.xml file right above the junit task declaration:

```
<path id="application" location="${jar.dir}/${ant.project.name}.jar"/>
```

which is a copy of the 'application' path id declaration within the 'run' task definition.

The application builds successfully, and I get the following output with **ant junit** (test failure is expected):

```
ant junit
Buildfile: /Users/jtyler/Projects/AntHelloWorld/build.xml

compile:
    [javac] /Users/jtyler/Projects/AntHelloWorld/build.xml:20: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds

jar:

junit:
    [junit] Running HelloWorldTest
    [junit] Tests run: 2, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Time elapsed: 0.001 sec
    [junit] Test HelloWorldTest FAILED

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 1 second
```

Comments the following questions would be greatly appreciated:

1. Is the fact I actually needed to include the junit.jar file in my lib folder something I should be concerned about? I would assume this is not necessary if ant's tutorial explicitly states *"Because Ant has a built-in JUnit 3.8.2 you could start directly using it."*
2. Is the fact I needed to define the 'application' path id outside of the run task definition a typo within the apache ant tutorial? Or are there other things I missed or should consider?

Thanks to all those that helped.

Answer (score 3):

The tutorial is misleading. The junit files that are included in ant do not work. I downloaded juinit and copied the jar file to the lib folder of the project and it now works fine.

Comment: Thank you for the validation!

Answer (score 1):

You must specify `junit.jar` itself in your compile and in your `<junit>` task's classpath. This is not automatically included in your compile:

```
<!--  Contains junit.jar and other needed test classes -->
<path id="junit.classpath">
    <fileset dir="${junit.directory}"/>
</path>

<!-- Contains third party jars your code is dependent upon -->
<path id="main.classpath">
    <fileset dir="${dependent.jar.dir}"/>
</path>

<!-- Your main Java source code directory -->
<property name="main.srcdir" value="${basedir}/src/main/java"/>

<!-- Your main Junit test directory source code -->
<property name="test.srcdir" value="${basedir}/src/test/java"/>

<!-- Where you're compiling your main classes to -->
<property name="main.destdir" value="${basedir}/target/classes"/>

<!-- Where you're compiling your test classes to -->
<property name="test.destdir" value="${basedir}/target/test-classes"/>
[...]

<!-- Compile Test Classes -->
<!-- Notice you have three classpath elements:
    * Your main classes you compiled before
    * Your test main classpath that your main classes
      were dependent up
    * The junit.jar classpath
-->

<javac destdir="${test.destdir}"
      srcdir="${test.srcdir}">
      <classpath>
          <!-- Your non-test classes you compiled before -->
          <pathelement path="${main.destdir}/> 
      </classpath>
      <classpath refid="junit.classpath"/>
      <classpath refid="main.classpath"/>
</javac>


<!-- Now run your unit tests: Note how you have the same
     three classpath elements as before -->

 <junit fork="yes">
     <classpath>
         <pathelement path="${main.destdir}"/>
         <pathelement path="${test.destdir}"/>
     </classpath>
      <classpath refid="main.classpath"/>
      <classpath refid="junit.classpath"/>
      [...]
  </junit>
```